# Mouse up event triggered while selecting text inside input, causes modal window to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div containing a form. When user clicks outside of the div it hides - this part works bit to good.

The problem is that while user is selecting text inside div(input, paragraph,...) and his mouse 
leaves the modal(clicked state), mouseup event is triggered which causes my div to hide.

How do I ignore the mouseup event when user is selecting text?

Here is what my HTML mark up looks like:

```
<div class="body">
    <button id="show-modal">Toggle modal</button>
    <div class="modal">
        <input type="text" name="opportunity-name" \>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.body {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
div.modal {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

JS:

```
var $modal = $('div.modal');
$('#show-modal').click(function () {
    $modal.fadeIn();
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('div.modal *, div.modal')) {
        $modal.fadeOut(100);
    }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psbxrrbc/1/)

Comment: What browser? I am not seeing the problem.

Comment: @epascarello: I'm using Safari v8 on OX Yosemite, but I've noticed this problem everywhere - just start selecting text inside `div.modal` and continue selecting to `div.body`(keep your mouse button pressed).

Comment: Um if you let go outside of course it is going to record it. WHy not listen for mousedown?

Comment: Oh, thank you, works just fine. I don't know why I kept trying to figure this out with mouseup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I ignore the mouseup event when user is selecting text?

Check if the text input has focus. Ex:

`if ( $(input).is(':focus') ) { ... }`

Comment: Yes! Thank you @elzi! This solution didn't cross my mind :/ Solved my problem.